# Find a bijection from $(A^B)^C$ into $A^{B \times C}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ for arbitrary cardinal numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57398/how-to-show-abc-abc-for-arbitrary-cardinal-numbers)

Notation: Let A and B be sets. The set of all functions $f:A \rightarrow B$ is denoted by $B^A$.

Problem: Let A, B, and C be sets. Show that there exists a bijection from $(A^B)^C$ into $A^{B \times C} $. You should first construct a function and then prove that it is a bijection.

What I have so far:

$f:C \rightarrow A^B$

$ f(c) : B \rightarrow A $

and

$ g : B \times C \rightarrow A $

$ g(b, c) \in A$

How do I find a bijection between these functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f \in (A^B)^C, g \in A^{B \times C}$. Define $\Phi: (A^B)^C \to A^{B \times C}$ by setting

$$\Phi(f)(b,c) = f(b)(c)$$

This is a bijection because it has an inverse $\Psi: A^{B \times C} \to (A^B)^C$

$$\Psi(g)(b)(c) = g(b,c)$$

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the notation $ f(b)(c) $. Does this imply a composition?

Comment: @BrandonK. It denotes two evaluations: $f$ is a function-valued function, so $f(b)$ is itself a function, so it can be evaluated at $c$ to get $f(b)(c)$.

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot more sense now.