# finding cardinality of set of all functions from Q to R

Tags: cardinals

suppose $f:Q→R$, how we can find cardinality of set of all possible functions $f$,I know it's probably the same as cardinality of real numbers but I can't think of any bijection for that or any other way to prove that.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ has the same cardinality as $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ so $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Q}}$ has the same cardinality as $2^{\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}} \cong 2^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  but does $(a^M)^K = a^{M\times K}$.  Do we *know* that?  (Of course once we *think* in those terms it's probably easy to come up with the bijection.)

Comment: Yes. This is currying: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Comment: @fleablood: Yes, [it’s easy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251168/proof-leftab-rightc-sim-a-leftb-times-c-right/251176#251176).

Comment: Yes, I was asking rhetorically for the sake of the OP.