# Two questions about cardinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, cardinals

I have two questions about set theory and cardinals.

1. I know that $k_1, k_2, m$ are cardinals. I also know that $k_1 \leq k_2$.
   I need to prove that $(k_1)^m \leq (k_2)^m$.
   I understand from what given that there is injective function between the sets of $k_1$ and $k_2$. I also know that if $|A| = |C|$, $|B|=|D|$ then $|B^A| = |D^C|$. so basically what I need to prove is that $k_2 \leq k_1$, and then with Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem say that if $k_1 \leq k_2$ and  $k_2 \leq k_1$ then $k_1 = k_2$, am I correct? I don't know how to continue from here.
2. the second question is that I need to prove that the set of relations on the set $N$ is $c$. I understand from the question that I need to prove that $|P(N \times N)|=c$, but I'm not sure and I don't know how to continue from here.

I'm just tired from all this discrete math, maybe anyone can recommend a good resource to read so I will understand it better.

Thank in advance.

Comment: The first one is shown also in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57389/how-to-prove-cardinality-equality-mathfrak-c-mathfrak-c-2-mathfrak-c/57393#57393).

Answer (score 2):

For the first question: you shouldn't need the fact on equality.  Instead, you can just use your injective function (say, $i$) from $k_1\to k_2$ to build an injective function $j$ from $k_1^m\to k_2^m$.  Using the characterization of $A^B$ as the set of functions from $B\to A$, your $j$ is a function that will take a *function* from $m\to k_1$ and return a new function from $m\to k_2$.  There's a very natural answer for how to build $j(f)$ given a function $f\in k_1^m$ and your injection $i$, and you should be able to prove that it works (that is, to prove that it's injective).

For the second question: do you know the notion of a pairing function?  That should be all that you need to solve this problem.