# The set of all real functions defined on [0,1] has cardinal number $2^c$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Prove that the set of all real functions defined on the closed unit interval [0,1] has cardinal number $2^c$.
it is easy to see that there exists as many as such functions i.e. the characteristic functions but I cannot prove the exact cardinality. so comments will be helpful

Comment: Any function can be identified with its graph, so the cardinality is at most that of the power set of $[0,1]\times\mathbb R$, i.e. $2^c$

Comment: Use the [fact that $\mathfrak c^\mathfrak c=2^\mathfrak c$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57389/how-to-prove-cardinality-equality-mathfrak-c-mathfrak-c-2-mathfrak-c) and $[0,1]\sim \Bbb R$.

Comment: Just below my comment above it says 'Trivial answer converted to comment'. Can anyone else see that?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks. It disappeared to me too as soon as I posted my question.

Comment: it is true that $c^c=2^c$, but I want to prove this @Git Gud

Comment: @SHIBASHIS Then just open the link above.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Use the fact that $|A^B|=|A|^{|B|}$, and show that $|\Bbb{R^R}|=2^{|\Bbb R|}$.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Etienne's comment, we have the following argument:

We have an injection from $\mathcal P([0,1])$ to the set of real functions on $[0,1]$ (which I will call $S$ for convenience) since each subset of $[0,1]$ can be mapped to a unique corresponding characteristic function.

On the other hand, we have an injection from $S$ to $\mathcal P([0,1]\times \mathbb R)$ since each real function in $S$ can be mapped to its unique graph in $[0,1]\times\mathbb R$.

From there, we have only to show that $\left|[0,1]\right|=\left|[0,1]\times\mathbb R\right|$

With the above, we have
$$
\left|\mathcal P([0,1])\right|\leq \left| S\right| \leq \left|\mathcal P([0,1]\times \mathbb R) \right|=\left|\mathcal P([0,1]) \right|
$$
Thus, $\mathcal P([0,1])$ and $S$ have equal cardinalities.